# VBA Autofilter passing dictionary.keys

Tags: vba

I'm new to VBA, so maybe this behavior is expected: when I'm passing a dict.keys array (in the documentation it is stated that `dictionary.keys` return an array) to `Autofilter`'s `Criteria1`, it filters only by one element in this array. Is there a workaround?

my subroutine works if I pass an array explicitly like this:

```
ReportWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$V$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array("Customer1", "Customer2", "Customer3")
```

It also works with one customer, but not when dictionary keys are being passed.
My Clientsname is of `Variant` type.

It is passed to my subroutine like this:

```
Main.GeneratingReport Customers.Keys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dictionary.keys` returns an array, indeed...

In order to understand what happens in your code, you should show us how do you load the criteria strings in the dictionary.

Anyhow, in order to use `Criteria` as array, you need `Operator:=xlFilterValues`

I would suggest you to (firstly) try the problematic line like (supposing that `Customers` is the needed dictionary):

```
ReportWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$V$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Customers.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

If it still does not work, then your dictionary is not loaded, or wrongly loaded. In such a case I would suggest you to use the next code lines, just before the above one:

```
Debug.Print Customers.Count: Stop
```

The code will stop on this line. Please check what it returns in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE). If it returns the correct/expected keys number, then try to see what is it inside it:

```
Dim El as Variant
For Each El in Customers.Keys
    Debug.Print El
Next
```

and see what it returns in Immediate Window.

Comment: thank you! The `Operator:=xlFilterValues` did the trick! Although I ended up using "CustomerName*" as a `Criteria1` because they always start the same, I will bear in mind your solution for more complex cases :)

Comment: @Herminne: Glad I could help!